# problem with System.Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use System.Activator.CreatInstance to Create an object based on the typeName.  I'm using the following code:

```
Object DataInstance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(
                      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                      "CMS.DataAccess.SQLWebSite");
IWebSite NewWebPage = (IWebSite)DataInstance;
```

`SQLWebSite` implements `IWebSite`.  But, I get the following error: *"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle' to type 'CMS.DataAccess.IWebSite'."*  Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `unwrap` after you call the `CreateInstance`, i.e.:

```
Object DataInstance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                                    "CMS.DataAccess.SQLWebSite").Unwrap();
            IWebSite NewWebPage = (IWebSite)DataInstance;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use the type name and not the strongly typed version of the method then you can do this:

```
var instance = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("CMS.DataAccess.SQLWebSite");
```

You could just use :

```
System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SQLWebSite))
```

But mabe you are trying not to have to reference the implementation in your code.